# ¿Como redirecciono un <td> a otra pagina html cuando el <td> muestra informacion traida de mysql?

Tags: php, html, css

Hola buenos dias me puede ayudar indicandome omo hago para que el  de Titulo_Art me redireccione a otra pagina html cuando uando el  muestra información traída de mysql.

```
<tr>
    <td height="37" ><?php echo $row -> Titulo_Art ?><a href="ArticuloNT1log.html"></a></td>
    <td height="37"><?php echo $row -> Descripcion ?></td>
    <td aling="center"><a href="eliminararticulo.php?Id_Articulos=<?php echo $row -> Id_Articulos?>"
    ><img src="Imagenes/eliminar.jpg" width="29" height="28" alt=""/></td>
</tr>
```

```
    <?php
        }
            ?>
        
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta poner la información de la base de datos dentro de las etiquetas

```
<td height="37" ><a href="ArticuloNT1log.html"><?php echo $row -> Titulo_Art ?></a></td>
```

Algo como así.